# Data Redundant for 2 NAS device

Tags: network-attached-storage

Wanna ask whether is it possible to have data redundant in 2 different NAS device under the same network?

I have a NAS device (Dlink 2 Bay Share Center) with 2x 1TB HDD configured in Raid 1. Of course I have no problem if either one of the HDD failure as Raid manage to repair itself or worst I replace another HDD with no data lost.

The problem is if the NAS casing itself is faulty due to lighting strike or some other reason there is very high possibility of losing data in both HDD even they are in Raid 1.

As most of the NAS aren't using NTFS or FAT32 format, I cant just simply take out the HDD and plug into PC and copy the data out. If I not mistaken the format is in ext2 or ext3. And to recover the ext2/ext3 files, I've been google for n x recovery software where I couldn't get any of it success. Futhermore it is 2x 1TB, it will take ages for recovery.

So, I'm thinking to get another same model of NAS device with same capacity and same configuration, can both of them get data redundant automatically? So that I can have 2x NAS with 2x 1TB each in Raid 1 configured, as so the possibility of losing both NAS is much much lower....

Answer (score 1):

Forget about such setup.

The word you are looking for is called a **backup**. It helps in the catastrophic scenario and you would still need it even if your RAID devices where completely fault tolerant, just to protect you from software and/or human error. If you have redundant NAS systems and you accidentally delete a file, it's gone on both systems immediately. With a (current) backup, you restore from the backup and proceed.

What you use for a backup is up to you, but it should be off-site to prevent data loss in case of a catastrophic event not only to your devices but your office, like a fire.